# Validate Grid view controls with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello all
I have a grid view which is bot bound with database but it is bound with datatable. Grid view has an empty row when first time the page is loaded. I am using this grid to insert data in database. Whenever user inserts a data in first row and clicks on "Add New Row" button, a new row is created. Now my problem is when user clicks on button I want to validate if there is any empty controls. So that I want to add javascript. I have trid many scripts but its not working. please guide me.

My grid view is as bellow.

**Qualification Detail**
        
                                    
                                
    
    
        
               
                
                
                
                  
                   
                     
                         
                             
                             
                                 
                                     
                                         Qualification
                                     
                                     
                                          
                                         --Select--

```
                                     </asp:DropDownList>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>
                                     Percentage
                                 </HeaderTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="percentageBox" clientID="percentageBox" name="percentageBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>
                                     Passing Year
                                 </HeaderTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="yearBox"  clientID="yearBox" name="yearBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>
                                     Institute Name
                                 </HeaderTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="instituteNameBox" clientID="instituteNameBox" name="instituteNameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                         <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" 
                             HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                     </asp:GridView>
                   </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
              </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="addRowBtn" EventName="Click"/>
                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created  a sample for validation in grid-view using J Query.You can take help from this one.

**JQUERY:**

```
var vIsProcess = true;
$("#btnSubmitNew").click(function(){
    $("table[id$='gvCommentSample']").find("input:text").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
    {
        alert("Please fill the required field");
        $(this).focus();
        vIsProcess= false;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        vIsProcess= true;
    }
 });
 if(!vIsProcess)
    return false;
 else
    return true;   
});
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCommentSample" runat="server" ShowFooter="false" Width="50%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitNew" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

**[CLICK ON THIS LINK TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/acomu4)**